# How to print the array column value using the if statement in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, pos

I am having a problem with my Static Point of Sale (POS) System in Java.

I'm using the 2D-Array with the help of a for-loop and if-statement but I've got a problem of displaying the Array Column on the receipt of my POS.

[POS Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhVlH.png)

```
public static void productdata(){

    for(int row = 0; row < Product.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 4 ; col++){
        Product[row][col] = "";

        }
    }
    for(int row = 0; row < POS.length; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < 3 ; col++){
    if(col == 0){
        POS[row][col] = "0";
    } else{
        POS[row][col] = "";
            }
        }
    }
    // Product [x] [y] x = row; y = col //
    Product [0] [0] = "PP1"; // PRODUCT CODE //
    Product [0] [1] = "\t9350"; // PRODUCT PRICE // 
    Product [0] [2] = "FVP PowerPack Guyabano\t\t\t\t"; // PRODUCT NAME //
    Product [0] [3] = "12"; // PRODUCT QUANTITY //
```

In the attached image I've showed the Array that I used for my Product Data. The problem there is, the receipt of the Product Purchased was showing the Product Code (*PP1*) [--see the small red box--] instead of the Product Name (*FVP PowerPack Guyabano*) [--see the violet box--], with that I don't know how to change it or display the Product Name...

[POS Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRIkb.png)

```
System.out.print("\n============================================================================");
    System.out.print("\n POS SYSTEM");
    System.out.print("\n FIRST VITA PLUS");
    System.out.print("\n 2/F Suntree Tower,");
    System.out.print("\n No. 13 Meralco Avenue,");
    System.out.print("\n Ortigas Center, Pasig City");
    System.out.print("\n 1605 Philippines\n");

    if (TryAgain == 'n' || TryAgain == 'N'){
        System.out.print("\n \t\t\t\t****PRODUCT PURCHASED****\n\n");
        stop4:
    for(int row = 0; row < POS.length; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){

            if((POS[row][col].equals("0")) || (POS[row][col].equals(""))){
                break stop4;
            } else{
        System.out.print(POS[row][col] + "\t");
            }
        }
            System.out.println();
            Double totalprice = Double.parseDouble(POS[row][2]);
            TOTAL = totalprice + TOTAL;
    }
    System.out.print("\n============================================================================");
```

...and on this part I've showed the Output and the method of how I created the receipt of the customer (with product code (that should be a product name), the product price and quantity was purchased).

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you please explain what is your problem actually ?

Comment: Sir @MeetTitan, yes sir I'm a student from Philippines and this is our Project, to create a Simple / Static Point of Sale from our choice Product Company, Restaurant, Coffee Shop etc. So I'm sorry if this code is not that good enough. And don't worry we will not deploy this PoS System.

Comment: Sir @Milos : in the attached photo 'POS Output1', as you can see there on the general output, the receipt of the product purchased, I want to change the 'PP1' (Product Code) with the Product Name (FVP PowerPack Guyabano), but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: You should not post your output as pictures, format it as code and put it into your question instead.

Comment: I am so sorry sir @T A , this my first time to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to print two dimensional array data.

You can try this :

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowLength; row++) 
 {
   for (int col = 0; col < colLength; col++)
    {
       System.out.print(arrayName[row][col]+" ");
     }
    System.out.print("\n");
 }
```